# Is it possible to use Parallax inside a Facebook App?

Tags: jquery, facebook, parallax

I was looking into tutorials and showcase on Parallax for webdesign and all of them use jQuery to achieve the desired results on the page. Is it possible to use Parallax effects inside Facebook Apps? Specially apps inside pages (Page Tab).

I've noticed that Facebook Tabs Apps do not work properly with some jQuery functions, so this might break the desired result for scrolling. Also, it will be inside an iframe and I've seen some bad results for parallax + iframes.

Reference of a good Parallax code: [Smashing Magazine Parallax Tutorial](http://www.richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/)

Comment: Is there an answer for that?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in an iframe? Unless you must scroll the entire page..

Comment: and that's the problem. YOu actually scroll the entire page and not the iframe....

Comment: Well, you could get rig of the scrollbars of the page by setting the canvas height via `FB.canvas.setHeight` and show a custom scrollbar inside the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Parallax is possible in a Facebook app. I myself have worked on [a Facebook app](https://www.facebook.com/ScotiabankGroupJM/app_465917743503465) that has some (weak) Parallax functionality. Certainly, Parallax isn't going to be as visually impressive in a small frame as it would be when the content is full-page, but it's entirely functionality possible. I'm not sure why anyone would think it wouldn't be.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go; AFAIK there's decent way to access the scroll-position from the outer-frame, so you'll have to scroll within the iframe to achieve your parallax-effect

Comment: Well, I'm creating a canvas app right now and my parallax isn't working. I even managed it to get the "scroll" value from the inner iframe to the skrollr script but it isn't working so far... But thanks for your feedback.